# Different MD5 between Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, hash, cryptography, md5

I want to compare MD5 hash from the same file. The file is sended as a byte[] through HTTP POST from Android, where I also calculate the hash and received from .NET server where I calculate again the hash and then want to compare them.

The problem is that for the same file I get different hashes...

Java code

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

try {

    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    fileInputStream.read(bFile);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

    int read = 0;
    while((read = fileInputStream.read(bFile)) != -1) {
        md.update(bFile, 0, read);
    }
    fileInputStream.close();

    byte[] mdBytes = md.digest();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0; i < mdBytes.length; ++i) {
        sb.append(Integer.toString((mdBytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
    }

    // generated MD5 is d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e


} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

C# code

```
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        string hexString = ToHex(md5.ComputeHash(stream), false);

        // Generated MD5 is d167df114a478809ef71fb7e10c40f8c
    }
}

public string ToHex(byte[] bytes, bool upperCase)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        result.Append(bytes[i].ToString(upperCase ? "X2" : "x2"));

    return result.ToString();
}
```

UPDATE

I've tried to change Java code to

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(int i=0; i < mdBytes.length; ++i) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02x", mdBytes[i]));
}
```

Result is always the same...

Comment: I think the problem relies on hexing the value, not getting MD5 of it.

Comment: think so as well...but cannot figure out where the bug is

Comment: Why do you use different ways to get string in HEX? I'm not sure what is happening in that code: `sb.append(Integer.toString((mdBytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));`

Comment: basically found the code on the net... :( need to check it...

Comment: I think you need to implement the same algorithms in both applications.

Comment: Try to convert the hash to Base64 string (C# and Java), instead of hexing it manually. You can also compare the bytes one by one as a test if the generated content is the same.

Comment: For hexing a byte[], you can use BitConverter.ToString(byte[]) and the remove the inline "-" and convert to the convenient case.

Comment: I'm no java guy, but in .Net streams, after reading the FileStream, you should seek back to the beginning before reading it all over again.

Comment: @Mihai you were right

Comment: @Stefano so, should I post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you read the file stream, you must seek back to the beginning of the stream in order to compute the hash properly.

Comment: Doesn't Java allow to nest streams on top of each other? For example, .Net surely does, so one can read a file stream just once, at the same time feeding it through the hasher. Not only it has performance benefits (a file doesn't have to be read twice) and allows to to process non-seekable streams (such as network), but also is more flexible and error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, halve your work by taking one (or more) of the many freely available tools to calculate MD5 hashes and see whether your C# or your Java code is correct (maybe both are wrong, okay :-)).

Then we'll see.

Update:

In the Java case you're reading the data into a byte array; afterwards you are using the same stream (already being EOF), thus never calling `md.update`.

Update 2:

So, write

```
[...]
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md.update(bFile, 0 , bFile.length);
byte[] mdBytes = md.digest();
[...]
```

and your basically fine. Btw, interesting technique of converting a byte array to a hex string ... :-) you may want to look for a better way, though ...

Comment: I've tried from http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm and hashes from the two files(server and client) are the same...so definitely algorithm bug

Comment: Oh, there is a misunderstanding. I've meant to use an external MD5 tool to check the results of your two *implementations* and find out whether at least one works. Not to check whether the file gets corrupted while being transferred. To be more concrete, check against the two MD5s being mentioned in the code comments.

Comment: @Mihai or because they use .Net as well :) LOL

Comment: @Stefano I doubt any of the java or .net hashing algorithms are faulty. Most likely it's your post hashing manipulations to blame.